# OR functionality on events using jquery

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have drop down list and onchange event I have an ajax call

```
$('#id').change(function() {
  // ajax call
});
```

But I want ajax call to be called :

- onchange
- onload

I have logic somewhat like this:

```
<script>
$function({

   myfunction();

   $('#id').change(function() {
      myfunction();
    });
});

function myfunction(){
// ajax call
}
</script>
```

But is there any efficient way of doing this, any jquery event that call handle both performing OR functionality like this:

```
if (onchange || onload)
// ajax call
```

I apologize for title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the event bound on two separate objects, not just two separate events, there isn't really a better way to do it than what you've written. If you wanted to bind two events to the same element, you could do the following:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
      $('#testElem').bind('load change', function()
      {
        $('body').append('I am fired!');
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Unfortunately, `<select>`s won't fire load events when the page loads, so you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Events

Multiple event types can be bound at once by including each one separated by a space:

```
$('#foo').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('entered');
});
```

From jquery api.